# Check grep return code

Tags: bash, unix, grep, exit-code

My script contains following sets in place:

```
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset
```

Now I would like o grep (not sed, awk, etc) for letter A in file b, and add the result to the file c:

```
grep A b >> C
```

The problem is that grep exits with RC 1 if no A is found in b file, which in my case is fine as I don't see that as an issue.
In that case I wrapped grep command in a function and run:

```
function func_1() {
  grep A b >> C
}

if func_1; then
  echo "OK"
else
  echo "STILL OK"
end
```

Everything works great, but soon I realised it would be nice to catch RC=2 (grep failure). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how that protects you from the effects of `set -e`

I think you'll need need a wrapper function that disables errexit for the duration, something like:

```
function func_2 {
    set +o errexit
    func_1 "$@"
    rc=$?
    set -o errexit
    echo "$rc"
}

case $(func_2) in
    0) echo "success" ;;
    1) echo "not found" ;;
    2) echo "trouble in grep-land" ;; 
esac
```

---

Reading closely the documentation for [`set -e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-set), you can handle commands with non-zero exit status in certain situations. However, you function cannot **return** a non-zero exit status:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit

function mygrep {
    local rc=0
    # on the left side of ||, errexit not triggered
    grep "$@" >/dev/null || rc=$?
#     return $rc         # nope, will trigger errexit
    echo $rc
}

echo "test 1: exit status 0"
mygrep $USER /etc/passwd

echo "test 2: exit status 1"
mygrep foobarbaz /etc/passwd

echo "test 2: exit status 2"
mygrep $USER /file_does_not_exist

echo done
```

outputs

```
test 1: exit status 0
0
test 2: exit status 1
1
test 2: exit status 2
grep: /file_does_not_exist: No such file or directory
2
done
```

Comment: disabling what is enabled is not a solution. I have to have set -o errexit at all times

Comment: Then you can never protect yourself from a non-zero exit status. Don't call grep or diff.

Comment: I dont want to protect myself from non-zero status, that's not the point. I want to know how to exit status of a function that has got set -o errexit

Comment: You can't. Read the documentation for `set -e`: "Exit  immediately  if [...] one of the commands executed as part  of
                      a  command  list  enclosed  by braces exits with a non-zero
                      status." A function is a command list in braces.

Comment: Actually, there will be a way. I have to run, but I'll be back to this later.